# Azure ARM Templates and REST API

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-api

I'm trying to learn Azure Resource Templates and am trying to understand the workflow behind when to use them and when to use the REST API.

My sense is that creating a Virtual Network and Subnets in Azure is a fairly uncommon occurance, once you get that set up as you want you don't modify it too frequently, you deploy things into that structure.

So with regard to an ARM Template let's say I have a template with resources for VNET and Subnet.  To take the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-template-walkthrough#virtual-network-and-subnet I might have:

```
{
"apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
"name": "[parameters('vnetName')]",
"location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
"properties": {
 "addressSpace": {
   "addressPrefixes": [
     "10.0.0.0/16"
   ]
 },
 "subnets": [
   {
     "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
     "properties": {
       "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
     }
   }
 ]
}
}
```

which I deploy to a Resource Group. Let's say I then add a Load Balancer and redeploy the template.  In this case the user then gets asked to supply the value for the vnetName parameter again and of course cannot supply the same value so we would end up with another VNET which is not what we want.

So is the workflow that you define your ARM Template (VNET, LBs, Subnets, NICs etc) in one go and then deploy?  Then when you want to deploy VMs, Scale Sets etc you use the REST API to deploy then to the Resource Group / VNET Subnet?  Or is there a way to incrementally build up an ARM Template and deploy it numerous times in a way that if a VNET already exists (for example) the user is not prompted to supply details for another one?

I've read around and seen incremental mode (default unless complete is specified) but not sure if this is relevant and if it is how to use it.

Many thanks for any help!

### Update

OK so I can now use `azure group deployment create -f azuredeploy.json -g ARM-Template-Tests -m Incremental` and have modified the VNET resource in my template from

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
  "name": "[variables('virtualNetworkName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "addressSpace": {
      "addressPrefixes": [
        "[variables('addressPrefix')]"
      ]
    },
    "subnets": [
      {
        "name": "[variables('subnetName')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "[variables('subnetPrefix')]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

to

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
  "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "properties": {
    "addressSpace": {
      "addressPrefixes": [
        "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
      ]
    },
    "subnets": [
      {
        "name": "[parameters('subnet1Name')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnet1Prefix')]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "[parameters('gatewaySubnet')]",
        "properties": {
          "addressPrefix": "[parameters('gatewaySubnetPrefix')]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

but the subnets don't change.  Should they using `azure group deployment create -f azuredeploy.json -g ARM-Template-Tests -m Incremental`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to piggy back on this Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy). Referencing appropriate section below:

> ### Incremental and complete deployments
>
> When deploying your resources,
>   you specify that the deployment is either an incremental update or a
>   complete update. By default, Resource Manager handles deployments as
>   incremental updates to the resource group.
>
> #### With incremental deployment, Resource Manager
>
> 1. **leaves unchanged** resources that exist in the resource group but are not specified in the template
> 2. **adds** resources that are specified in the template but do not exist in the resource group
> 3. **does not reprovision** resources that exist in the resource group in the same condition defined in the template
> 4. **reprovisions** existing resources that have updated settings in the template
>
> #### With complete deployment, Resource Manager:
>
> 1. **deletes** resources that exist in the resource group but are not specified in the template
> 2. **adds** resources that are specified in the template but do not exist in the resource group
> 3. **does not reprovision** resources that exist in the resource group in the same condition defined in the template
> 4. **reprovisions** existing resources that have updated settings in the template

To choose Incremental update or Complete update it depends on if you have resources that are in use. If devops requirement is to always have resources in sync with what is defined in the json template then `Complete Update` mode should be used. The biggest benefit of using templates and source code for deploying resources is to prevent configuration drift and it is beneficial to use `Complete Update` mode.

As for specifying the parameters if you specify in parameters file then you don't have to specify them again.

Comment: do you know how to use incremental update via cli rather than powershell?

Comment: @StuartBrown `azure group deployment create -m "Incremental" -g "resource group name" -n "name of the deployment"`.  For more help use `azure group deployment create -h`

Comment: thanks!  I've added an update to my question, would you expect the kind of change I have made to my template to applied via an incremental deployment?

Comment: You should use complete instead of incremental because you changed your subnet.

Comment: many thanks!  i will mark yours as the right answer!  One final clarification - in examples such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#linking-to-a-template incremental mode is set in the template at resource level.  Why is that method used? Can one resource in a template have method of incremental and another Complete?

Comment: No it cannot. But if you think logically this mode property is for deployment. So in that example see the type, it is deployment. In other words if the resource type is deployment then you can have mode property.

Answer (score 1):

A new template can be deployed in incremental mode which would add new resources to the existing resource group. Define only the new resources in the template, existing resources would not be altered.

From powershell use the following cmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "YourResourceGroupName" -TemplateFile "path\to\template.json" -Mode Incremental -Force

Comment: thanks!  I had been looking on the CLI version of the docs around this but it doesn't show the flags for incremental mode https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-cli.   You say `Define only the new resources in the template, existing resources would not be altered.`  Do you mean I can use the same template and add new resources and the existing resources / requests for user to enter params wont be affected?  I have seen examples of the deployment mode being set on the resource in the template too. Is there a difference?

Comment: We keep a template which contains all the resources in the resource group. It would be used for a disaster recovery or in case the resource group would need to be moved to a different region. For new release deployments we run a fresh template where only new resources are defined. You can have all the resources defined in one template and run the new release deployments. It should work fine, as per documentation Azure "does not reprovision resources that exist in the resource group in the same condition defined in the template". (continued below)

Comment: However I had bad experience in the past when running a script with all the resources defined deleted and recreated an existing VM which had manually configured AD on it. Luckily it was a test environment, but still caused some trouble. 
Probably worth doing test with all resources defined in the template and go for it if it works well. After having issues in the past I decided not to take further risks which could screw the environment. By defining only new resources in the template I'm confident that existing resources would not be reprovisioned.

Answer (score 0):

My rule of thumb is for things that I want to tear down, or for things I want to replicate across Subscriptions, I use ARM templates.

For example we want things in test environments, I just ARM it up, build on the scripts as developers request things ("Hey I need a cache", "Oh by the way I need to start using a Service Bus"), using incremental mode we can just push it out to Dev, then as we migrate up to different environments you just deploy to a different Subscription in Azure, and it *should* have everything ready to go.

Also, we've started provisioning our own Cloud Load Test agents in a VMSS, a simple ARM template that's called by a build to scale up to *x* number of machines, then when done, we just trash the Resource Group.  It's repeatable and reliable, sure you can script it up, but as TFS has a task to deploy these things (also with schedules)...

One of the beautiful things I've come across is Key Vault, when you ARM it up and poke all the values from your service busses, storage accounts/whatevers, you can simply get the connection strings/keys/whatevers and put them straight into the Key Vault, so you never need to worry about it, and if you want to regenerate anything (say a dev wants to change the name of a cache or whatever, or accidentally posted the key to GitHub), just redeploy (often I'll just trash the whole Resource Group) and it updates the vault for you.