# ARM ADF Deployment Features

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I am not sure that this is the appropriate forum but we are having some issues with the recommended [CI/CD flow for Azure Datafactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment) which is requiring us to create our own script to deploy ADF resources using the ADF REST APIs instead of auto-generated ARM templates.

Before undertaking this work, we wanted to clarify a few assumptions about the ARM template deployment for ADF resources. Are all of the assumptions true?

- ARM template deployment for ADF resources simply calls the ADF REST APIs to deploy resources and has the same limitations as calling the REST APIs ourselves?
- ARM template deployment for ADF does not perform any optimizations before calling the REST APIs such as reading the current definition of resources before writing and only writing if the definition has changed.

Are there any other ARM limitations or optimizations that we should be aware of in order to make sure that our performance is as optimal as ARM?

Comment: What do you mean by creating your own script ? the CI CD flow for ADF generates an ARM template that is calling the ARM API. What problem are you trying to address ?

Answer (score 0):

As we know An [ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview) is a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) file that defines the infrastructure and configuration for your project. The template uses declarative syntax. In declarative syntax, you describe your intended deployment without writing the sequence of programming commands to create the deployment.

ARM has its own benefits over REST APIs such as Incremental and complete deployments which are not available when using the REST APIs.

[David Gaspard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12658745/david-gaspard): Coming to your ask, ARM Templet is collection of JSON defines where you can include multiple REST APIs calls in single module and use it for deployment. You can re-use. It also allows you to use Variables. It dependence on what best suits for your requirement.

You can use incremental deployment in ARM which can take care of Optimization.

Few reference that might help.

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-rest
2. related discussion : [Azure ARM Templates and REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508244/azure-arm-templates-and-rest-api)
3. ARM Limitations : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/best-practices